# Can / how do I identify which step in an SSIS package failed from SSIS logs?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

If I have a SQL Agent job that runs an SSIS package and that SSIS package fails. Is it possible / how do I identify which step in the SSIS package failed?

My end goal is to write a query that will tell me the last step that failed. So far I have:

```
select top 5 * from MyDB.dbo.sysssislog 
where event = 'OnError'
order by id desc
```

This gives me a SourceID, which is the GUID of the package (which I already know from SQL Agent view history). It also gives me executionid, which I haven't been able to match up to anything.

I found the Microsoft docs useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/views-integration-services-catalog, however, I wasn't able to identify which step in the package caused the problem. I am wondering if it is possible at all - if SSIS simple doesn't store this information.

Comment: This has been answered on this thread [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118737/how-to-query-ssisdb-to-find-out-the-errors-in-the-packages).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you just want to check it yourself you can see logging from your executed SSIS package in your SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: SSMS]

Comment: It would've been nicer if I could get something in query form because then I could reuse it in other ways (e.g. automated SSRS reports), but this meets my needs.